# A matrix and linearly independent vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a matrix, and let  and  be linearly independent vectors such that =,=+2.Then we have that $\mathbf{A}^{5} \mathbf{x} = a \mathbf{x} + b\mathbf{y}$ for some scalars  and .  Find the ordered pair (a, b).

So far I have $\mathbf{A}^{5}x = \mathbf{A}^{4}y$

$\mathbf{A}^{4}y = \mathbf{A}^{3}x + 2\mathbf{A}^{3}y$

I'm a bit stuck how to derive the pair (a, b)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Keep going.  $\mathbf A^3 x=\mathbf A^2 y$ and $2\mathbf A^3 y=2\mathbf A^2( x+2 y)$

Comment: Thank you! After a few manipulations I have $\mathbf{A}^{5}x = 5Ax + 12Ay$. Hence, a = 5 and b = 12.

Comment: Keep going.  Use $\mathbf Ax=y$ and $\mathbf Ay=x+2y$ once more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reduce the powers, which works if you keep going. You can increase them as well. If $Ax=y$ and $Ay = x+2y$, then
$$
\begin{split}
A^2 x &= A(Ax) = Ay = x+2y\\
A^2 y &= A(x+2y) = Ax +2Ay = y + 2(x+2y) = 2x + 5y\\
A^3 x &= A^2y = 2x + 5y\\
A^4 x &= A^3 y = A(2x+5y) = 2y+5(x+2y) = 5x+12y
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you! I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track.  Here are the next steps.

$\mathbf A^3 x=\mathbf A^2 y$ and $2\mathbf A^3 y=2\mathbf A^2( x+2 y)$.

$\mathbf A^2y=\mathbf A\mathbf Ay=\mathbf A(x+2y)$ and $2\mathbf A\mathbf Ax+4\mathbf A \mathbf Ay=2\mathbf Ay+4\mathbf A(x+2y)$.

Can you take it from here?